# Mount remote drive by port forwarding

Tags: windows, linux, ssh, mount, ssh-tunnel

I have a windows 7 computer at home and a remote windows XP machine with an external USB drive attached to it.  I would like to be able to copy files to and from home/the remote USB drive. The problem is that the only way of contacting the work computer is by first sshing into a different remote linux machine as there is a firewall that prevents direct internet connection.

I can see two possible solutions but I don't know how to do them.

- Set up winscp using ssh port forwarding via the linux box so that I can copy to and from the two windows machines.  I assume that I would need to run an ssh server on the XP machine as well to do this?
- Mounting the remote USB drive on the remote windows machine from the home XP machine via ssh port forwarding again via the linux box.

Does anyone know how to do either solution?

Comment: FabulaTech has a program called USB over Network which will let you share USB devices over the network.  This program works VERY well.  I used it to share an Epson scanner between a few different workstations.  The downside is that this is software that you will have to purchase eventually.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup reverse ssh between windows machines for direct connection. Cygwin is one option.

http://brendonrobinson.wordpress.com/2011/09/11/ssh-through-firewalls-using-a-reverse-ssh-tunnel/

If remote machine is at your work please keep in mind that your employer (IT guy) will be able to see a persistent ssh connection and usually it's not something that a company's IT would appreciate since you're esentially punching trough their security.

Answer (score 0):

You could sign up with [LogMeIn](http://logmein.com), their Pro edition lets you remote in to the Windows XP box through your browser and transfer files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebDAV over ssh-forwarded http port.

On first, "server" XP:

- Install IIS (Control panel, Add/remove programs, check "Internet Information Services").
- Share some folder (Right ckick, properies, Web Sharing tab, check "share this folder", set permissions).

On second, "client" XP:

- Make sure local port 80 is not used - xp can only connect to webdav server on port 80 (`netstat -na`)
- Start your ssh with port forwarding (`ssh -L 80:first_xp_address:80 linux_box_address`)
- Connect to shared folder (Windows explorer, menu, Tools, Map network drive, "Connect to a web site", next, next, enter `http://localhost/remote_share_name`).